# guard let cause , returns from the entire function block

Tags: ios, swift

The following code returns from *`guard let details`* but it does not execute the other print statments.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let testDictionary:[String:AnyObject] = ["a":NSMutableArray()]

    let result = testDictionary["C"]

    print("Before details Check")
    guard let details = result where details.isKindOfClass(NSArray) else {
        return false
    }
    print("Returned Result \(details)")
    print("After Details Check")
    return true
}
```

Any reason why the statements after gaurd are not being executed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: This sounds like expected behavior. As designed. Maybe you should have `where !details.isKindOfClass(NSArray)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ["Statements"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) in the Swift documentation:

> **Return Statement**
>
> A `return` statement occurs in the body of a function or method
>   definition and causes program execution to return to the calling
>   function or method.

and

> **Guard Statement**
>
> A `guard` statement is used to transfer program control out of a scope
>   if one or more conditions aren’t met.
>   ...
>   The `else` clause of a guard statement is required, and must either call
>   a function marked with the noreturn attribute or transfer program
>   control outside the guard statement’s enclosing scope ...

If your `guard let details =` condition fails then `return` 
"immediately" returns from the current function. You cannot simply
continue because `details` would be undefined. That is exactly what
the `guard` statement is made for.

You could solve your problem by introducing a local scope:

```
print("Before details Check")
checkLabel: do {
    guard let details = result where details.isKindOfClass(NSArray) else {
        break checkLabel
    }
    print("Returned Result \(details)")
}
print("After details Check")
```

Here, `break checkLabel` continues execution after the `do`-scope if
the condition failed.

But a much simpler way would be to use `if-let` instead of `guard-let`:

```
print("Before details Check")
if let details = result where details.isKindOfClass(NSArray) {
    print("Returned Result \(details)")
}
print("After details Check")
```

Comment: For the above code details! was not required. But, at some places where I use NSJONSerilization.JSONObjectWithData I have to use the force unwrapping  (if let details = result where details!.isKindOfClass(NSArray))

Answer (score 0):

You create the test dictionary with one item having a key of "a". Then you ask for an object from that same dictionary with key of "C". "details" is of course nil so you return false.

Comment: That's correct. I am basically checking the gaurd statement, whether it throws a exception or error (crash). Its just for testing. But, I came to this scenario where return of guard returns from the entire function.

Comment: It's doing exactly what it should. Read up on guard.